# How would I add volume on to the current_volume list in pyalsaaudio?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyalsaaudio

I'm trying to add on volume to a current set volume, in this case we will say it's 80%. Using the alsaaudio module in Python, there is a function called `getvolume`

```
#declare alsaaudio
am = alsaaudio.Mixer()
#get current volume
current_volume = am.getvolume()
```

`getvolume` or `current_volume` in my case dumps a list such as `[80L]` for 80% volume. I am trying to add volume on to the current one like this,

```
#adds 5 on to the current_volume    
increase = current_volume + 5
am.setvolume(increase)
```

But my problem is, since it's a list I cannot strip or replace characters and since I am relatively new to Python, have no clue on how to strip the characters in the list and then add 5 on to that integer after converting.

I created a run-able example here:

```
import alsaaudio
am = alsaaudio.Mixer()
current_volume = am.getvolume()
print(repr(current_volume), type(current_volume), type(current_volume[0]))
```

It prints:
 `('[45L]', <type 'list'>, <type 'long'>)`, even though this issue is solved, thanks for your responses.

Comment: For starters, fix your formatting. Whitespace is crucial in Python.

Comment: Secondly, show an actual runnable example and the resulting error with stacktrace. Ihave no idea what [80L] is supposed to mean. It seems to be invalid syntax (I just checked to make sure I'm not missing something).

Comment: Now that I've fixed your formatting for you, the most useful piece of information you can show is the result of `print(repr(current_volume), type(current_volume))`. That should clarify any ambiguity about what that value is, so I can presumably answer your question.

Comment: The "format [%L]" is something you made up. Please show the actual output. Kudos for responding quickly though. Could you make it `print(repr(current_volume), type(current_volume), type(current_volume[0]))`?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you provide the printout I asked for though?

Comment: You should probably mention that you are using Python 2 in the tags. `80L` is very much a Python 2 thing. I haven't used it for so long, I'd forgotten all about it. Kudos on a well posed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mixer.getvolume([direction])

Returns a list with the current volume settings for each channel. The list elements are integer percentages.

https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/91452/alsaaudio.Mixer

```
    mixer = alsaaudio.Mixer()
    value = mixer.getvolume()[0]
    value = value + 5
    if value > 100:
        value = 100
    mixer.setvolume(value)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/), [`Mixer.getvolume`](https://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/libalsaaudio.html#alsaaudio.Mixer.getvolume) returns a list of integer percentages, with one element for each channel. The docs for [`Mixer.setvolume`](https://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/libalsaaudio.html#alsaaudio.Mixer.setvolume) are less clear, but apear to imply that the first argument is an integer.

If my interpretation is correct, and you have only one channel, you can use [list indexing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) to get the first element of the list as an integer. The other steps are as you show in the question. You may want to make sure that the incremented result is less than or equal to 100. The [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function provides a standard idiom to do that:

```
import alsaaudio

am = alsaaudio.Mixer()
current_volume = am.getvolume()
new_volume = min(current_volume[0] + 5, 100)
am.setvolume(new_volume)
```

I've submitted [issue #58](https://github.com/larsimmisch/pyalsaaudio/issues/58) to pyalsaaudio to get the docs clarified a bit.

Comment: This way works perfectly fine too, thanks for your response!

Comment: @Daquaney. It's functionally identical to the accepted answer. I've submitted an issue to the library on github to see if they will fix up their docs a bit.